# Unplausible path for pickup and delivery problem using ortools

Tags: python, optimization, shortest-path, or-tools, vehicle-routing

So im trying to solve a pick up and delivery problem and I use python for that the code looks like this:

```
or_tool_data = {
        'distance_matrix': GraphMapper.to_distance_matrix(mapNodes),
        'pickups_deliveries': 
TransportrequestMapper.to_pickups_deliveries(request.json.get('transport_requests')),
        'depot': 1,
        'num_vehicles': 1,
}

manager = pywrapcp.RoutingIndexManager(len(or_tool_data['distance_matrix']),
                                       or_tool_data['num_vehicles'], or_tool_data['depot'])

routing = pywrapcp.RoutingModel(manager)

def distance_callback(from_index, to_index):
    """Returns the manhattan distance between the two nodes."""
    # Convert from routing variable Index to distance matrix NodeIndex.
    from_node = manager.IndexToNode(from_index)
    to_node = manager.IndexToNode(to_index)
    return or_tool_data['distance_matrix'][from_node][to_node]

transit_callback_index = routing.RegisterTransitCallback(distance_callback)
routing.SetArcCostEvaluatorOfAllVehicles(transit_callback_index)

# Add Distance constraint.
dimension_name = 'Distance'
routing.AddDimension(
    transit_callback_index,
    0,  # no slack
    3000,  # vehicle maximum travel distance
    True,  # start cumul to zero
    dimension_name)
distance_dimension = routing.GetDimensionOrDie(dimension_name)
distance_dimension.SetGlobalSpanCostCoefficient(100)

for transport_request in or_tool_data['pickups_deliveries']:
    pickup_index = manager.NodeToIndex(transport_request[0])
    delivery_index = manager.NodeToIndex(transport_request[1])
    routing.AddPickupAndDelivery(pickup_index, delivery_index)
    routing.solver().Add(
        routing.VehicleVar(pickup_index) == routing.VehicleVar(
            delivery_index))
    routing.solver().Add(
        distance_dimension.CumulVar(pickup_index) <=
        distance_dimension.CumulVar(delivery_index))


# Setting first solution heuristic.
search_parameters = pywrapcp.DefaultRoutingSearchParameters()
search_parameters.first_solution_strategy = (
    routing_enums_pb2.FirstSolutionStrategy.PARALLEL_CHEAPEST_INSERTION)

# Solve the problem.
solution = routing.SolveWithParameters(search_parameters)
```

Im invoking it with the following data:

pickups_deliveries:

```
[[52, 41]]
```

distance_matrix:

```
[[0, 24, 49, 56, 26, 70, 71, 65, 66, 29, 75, 64, 68, 17, 38, 34, 41, 35, 53, 68, 50, 19, 69, 3, 58, 50, 46, 9, 76, 44, 53, 16, 51, 72, 69, 57, 44, 64, 59, 10, 59, 11, 77, 40, 38, 16, 65, 30, 51, 37, 44, 26, 23, 58, 69, 68, 79, 40, 21, 38, 30, 30, 57, 68, 76, 11, 20, 73, 33, 26], [24, 0, 60, 70, 2, 84, 95, 88, 88, 36, 98, 87, 88, 36, 58, 58, 17, 46, 72, 87, 71, 41, 84, 24, 80, 68, 57, 31, 100, 62, 75, 26, 61, 85, 83, 80, 55, 78, 83, 32, 73, 13, 101, 63, 54, 23, 82, 54, 68, 61, 68, 6, 44, 80, 93, 87, 103, 64, 30, 62, 33, 53, 79, 87, 99, 25, 8, 97, 47, 14], [49, 60, 0, 97, 62, 110, 73, 53, 50, 24, 91, 48, 100, 33, 75, 46, 70, 81, 89, 34, 35, 36, 108, 51, 48, 87, 91, 53, 84, 82, 76, 35, 97, 25, 24, 77, 5, 104, 62, 55, 15, 53, 90, 40, 80, 38, 102, 59, 19, 49, 50, 56, 32, 84, 81, 35, 84, 55, 70, 49, 78, 36, 45, 100, 65, 60, 52, 67, 16, 71], [56, 70, 97, 0, 71, 14, 67, 80, 84, 84, 52, 84, 24, 66, 22, 55, 85, 25, 14, 100, 77, 61, 14, 53, 75, 12, 15, 47, 62, 16, 36, 71, 15, 115, 109, 40, 92, 8, 63, 46, 100, 61, 57, 64, 18, 71, 13, 38, 89, 54, 58, 75, 65, 31, 55, 99, 68, 49, 40, 54, 40, 62, 77, 24, 84, 47, 71, 77, 81, 59], [26, 2, 62, 71, 0, 85, 97, 90, 90, 38, 100, 89, 89, 38, 59, 60, 15, 47, 73, 89, 73, 43, 85, 26, 83, 69, 58, 33, 102, 64, 77, 28, 62, 87, 85, 82, 57, 79, 85, 34, 75, 15, 103, 65, 55, 25, 83, 56, 70, 63, 70, 6, 46, 81, 95, 89, 105, 67, 31, 64, 33, 55, 81, 89, 101, 26, 10, 99, 49, 14], [70, 84, 110, 14, 85, 0, 73, 89, 93, 98, 54, 93, 23, 80, 35, 67, 98, 38, 23, 111, 88, 75, 3, 67, 85, 23, 27, 61, 66, 28, 43, 85, 25, 128, 121, 47, 105, 6, 71, 60, 113, 75, 59, 76, 32, 86, 10, 51, 101, 65, 69, 89, 78, 36, 59, 110, 72, 60, 54, 66, 53, 75, 87, 22, 91, 61, 85, 84, 94, 73], [71, 95, 73, 67, 97, 73, 0, 24, 28, 79, 25, 30, 52, 64, 53, 38, 112, 74, 53, 53, 38, 56, 71, 71, 26, 56, 75, 65, 13, 55, 32, 76, 79, 77, 69, 27, 71, 71, 12, 65, 66, 82, 21, 36, 63, 78, 63, 44, 55, 34, 28, 96, 55, 37, 15, 51, 11, 31, 77, 33, 85, 45, 29, 53, 19, 74, 90, 11, 66, 94], [65, 88, 53, 80, 90, 89, 24, 0, 4, 64, 48, 6, 70, 53, 61, 32, 104, 79, 67, 29, 19, 47, 87, 66, 8, 69, 84, 62, 37, 65, 46, 65, 89, 53, 45, 43, 52, 85, 19, 62, 43, 76, 45, 26, 70, 68, 79, 47, 34, 31, 24, 88, 44, 54, 37, 27, 35, 32, 78, 30, 86, 35, 9, 71, 12, 72, 81, 15, 50, 91], [66, 88, 50, 84, 90, 93, 28, 4, 0, 63, 52, 2, 74, 53, 64, 34, 104, 82, 71, 25, 18, 47, 90, 67, 9, 72, 87, 63, 41, 69, 50, 64, 92, 49, 41, 48, 49, 89, 23, 64, 40, 77, 49, 26, 73, 67, 83, 50, 31, 33, 26, 88, 44, 58, 42, 23, 39, 35, 79, 32, 88, 36, 9, 75, 15, 73, 81, 19, 48, 92], [29, 36, 24, 84, 38, 98, 79, 64, 63, 0, 91, 61, 93, 19, 64, 44, 46, 64, 79, 54, 45, 26, 97, 32, 57, 76, 75, 37, 88, 70, 72, 13, 81, 49, 48, 75, 20, 92, 67, 38, 38, 31, 92, 43, 66, 15, 92, 51, 36, 48, 52, 32, 25, 79, 83, 55, 89, 53, 50, 48, 58, 34, 55, 93, 76, 40, 28, 77, 15, 47], [75, 98, 91, 52, 100, 54, 25, 48, 52, 91, 0, 54, 31, 73, 45, 48, 115, 66, 39, 76, 58, 66, 51, 75, 48, 43, 64, 67, 13, 44, 23, 85, 66, 99, 91, 19, 88, 53, 30, 67, 87, 86, 5, 51, 54, 87, 44, 45, 75, 44, 41, 101, 67, 22, 11, 74, 19, 38, 74, 44, 80, 58, 51, 32, 44, 75, 95, 36, 81, 94], [64, 87, 48, 84, 89, 93, 30, 6, 2, 61, 54, 0, 75, 51, 64, 33, 102, 81, 71, 23, 16, 46, 91, 66, 9, 72, 86, 62, 43, 69, 51, 62, 91, 47, 39, 48, 47, 89, 24, 62, 38, 75, 51, 25, 73, 65, 83, 49, 29, 32, 26, 86, 43, 58, 43, 21, 41, 35, 78, 31, 87, 34, 8, 76, 17, 72, 80, 21, 46, 90], [68, 88, 100, 24, 89, 23, 52, 70, 74, 93, 31, 75, 0, 74, 30, 55, 103, 45, 16, 95, 73, 67, 20, 67, 67, 20, 39, 59, 43, 25, 25, 82, 39, 114, 107, 27, 96, 23, 51, 58, 100, 77, 36, 62, 34, 83, 13, 42, 88, 51, 53, 92, 70, 17, 37, 94, 49, 46, 59, 52, 61, 64, 69, 1, 70, 63, 87, 63, 86, 79], [17, 36, 33, 66, 38, 80, 64, 53, 53, 19, 73, 51, 74, 0, 45, 26, 51, 49, 60, 52, 35, 8, 79, 19, 45, 58, 59, 21, 71, 52, 53, 12, 65, 56, 52, 56, 28, 74, 51, 22, 42, 25, 74, 28, 48, 15, 73, 32, 34, 30, 36, 35, 9, 60, 65, 52, 73, 35, 37, 31, 46, 18, 44, 74, 64, 28, 29, 63, 16, 42], [38, 58, 75, 22, 59, 35, 53, 61, 64, 64, 45, 64, 30, 45, 0, 34, 74, 22, 15, 79, 56, 40, 34, 36, 55, 13, 23, 29, 51, 7, 22, 52, 28, 93, 87, 28, 70, 29, 45, 28, 79, 46, 49, 42, 10, 53, 28, 16, 67, 32, 38, 61, 43, 23, 43, 78, 56, 29, 30, 33, 35, 40, 56, 30, 66, 33, 56, 60, 59, 50], [34, 58, 46, 55, 60, 67, 38, 32, 34, 44, 48, 33, 55, 26, 34, 0, 75, 49, 45, 45, 22, 19, 65, 35, 25, 45, 55, 29, 45, 40, 31, 38, 60, 61, 54, 32, 42, 62, 25, 30, 46, 45, 48, 9, 42, 41, 59, 17, 34, 4, 10, 59, 19, 39, 39, 44, 47, 10, 45, 4, 54, 10, 25, 55, 42, 40, 52, 39, 33, 59], [41, 17, 70, 85, 15, 98, 112, 104, 104, 46, 115, 102, 103, 51, 74, 75, 0, 60, 87, 100, 86, 57, 98, 41, 96, 83, 70, 48, 117, 78, 92, 40, 74, 95, 94, 97, 66, 92, 100, 49, 84, 30, 118, 79, 69, 37, 97, 71, 81, 78, 85, 16, 60, 96, 110, 100, 120, 81, 45, 79, 45, 69, 95, 103, 115, 41, 22, 113, 60, 25], [35, 46, 81, 25, 47, 38, 74, 79, 82, 64, 66, 81, 45, 49, 22, 49, 60, 0, 30, 93, 71, 46, 38, 32, 73, 26, 11, 28, 73, 22, 44, 51, 17, 103, 98, 49, 76, 32, 65, 27, 88, 38, 70, 57, 12, 51, 37, 32, 78, 49, 55, 51, 51, 44, 65, 92, 78, 47, 16, 50, 16, 52, 73, 45, 86, 25, 48, 80, 65, 35], [53, 72, 89, 14, 73, 23, 53, 67, 71, 79, 39, 71, 16, 60, 15, 45, 87, 30, 0, 89, 66, 54, 21, 51, 62, 4, 25, 44, 48, 9, 22, 67, 27, 105, 99, 26, 84, 18, 49, 43, 91, 61, 43, 53, 18, 68, 14, 29, 79, 42, 46, 76, 57, 17, 41, 87, 54, 38, 43, 43, 45, 53, 64, 16, 70, 47, 71, 63, 74, 63], [68, 87, 34, 100, 89, 111, 53, 29, 25, 54, 76, 23, 95, 52, 79, 45, 100, 93, 89, 0, 23, 49, 109, 70, 29, 89, 100, 68, 66, 85, 70, 61, 106, 25, 17, 69, 36, 107, 46, 70, 20, 77, 73, 36, 87, 64, 102, 63, 18, 47, 42, 85, 45, 78, 65, 2, 63, 51, 86, 46, 95, 41, 26, 96, 38, 78, 79, 43, 40, 94], [50, 71, 35, 77, 73, 88, 38, 19, 18, 45, 58, 16, 73, 35, 56, 22, 86, 71, 66, 23, 0, 31, 86, 51, 13, 66, 77, 48, 50, 62, 48, 47, 83, 42, 34, 47, 33, 84, 28, 49, 29, 60, 56, 13, 64, 50, 79, 40, 17, 24, 20, 70, 27, 56, 48, 22, 49, 28, 65, 23, 74, 20, 10, 74, 31, 58, 64, 33, 30, 76], [19, 41, 36, 61, 43, 75, 56, 47, 47, 26, 66, 46, 67, 8, 40, 19, 57, 46, 54, 49, 31, 0, 73, 21, 39, 52, 56, 19, 64, 47, 46, 19, 62, 57, 52, 49, 31, 69, 44, 21, 42, 29, 66, 22, 44, 22, 68, 25, 33, 23, 28, 41, 4, 53, 58, 49, 66, 28, 37, 23, 46, 12, 38, 67, 58, 28, 35, 56, 20, 45], [69, 84, 108, 14, 85, 3, 71, 87, 90, 97, 51, 91, 20, 79, 34, 65, 98, 38, 21, 109, 86, 73, 0, 67, 82, 21, 28, 61, 63, 27, 40, 85, 26, 126, 119, 44, 104, 6, 68, 59, 111, 75, 56, 74, 31, 85, 8, 49, 99, 63, 67, 89, 77, 34, 57, 108, 69, 58, 54, 64, 53, 73, 84, 19, 88, 61, 85, 81, 93, 73], [3, 24, 51, 53, 26, 67, 71, 66, 67, 32, 75, 66, 67, 19, 36, 35, 41, 32, 51, 70, 51, 21, 67, 0, 59, 48, 43, 8, 76, 42, 52, 19, 49, 75, 71, 56, 46, 61, 60, 8, 61, 11, 77, 41, 36, 18, 63, 30, 53, 38, 45, 26, 25, 57, 69, 70, 79, 40, 18, 39, 27, 32, 58, 66, 77, 9, 21, 73, 35, 25], [58, 80, 48, 75, 83, 85, 26, 8, 9, 57, 48, 9, 67, 45, 55, 25, 96, 73, 62, 29, 13, 39, 82, 59, 0, 64, 78, 54, 38, 60, 43, 57, 83, 51, 43, 40, 46, 81, 17, 55, 40, 69, 45, 18, 64, 60, 75, 41, 29, 24, 17, 80, 37, 50, 37, 27, 37, 26, 70, 23, 79, 28, 3, 68, 19, 64, 74, 20, 43, 84], [50, 68, 87, 12, 69, 23, 56, 69, 72, 76, 43, 72, 20, 58, 13, 45, 83, 26, 4, 89, 66, 52, 21, 48, 64, 0, 21, 41, 52, 6, 24, 65, 24, 105, 98, 29, 83, 18, 51, 40, 90, 57, 47, 53, 14, 65, 16, 28, 79, 43, 47, 72, 56, 21, 44, 88, 57, 38, 39, 43, 41, 52, 65, 20, 72, 44, 67, 65, 72, 59], [46, 57, 91, 15, 58, 27, 75, 84, 87, 75, 64, 86, 39, 59, 23, 55, 70, 11, 25, 100, 77, 56, 28, 43, 78, 21, 0, 39, 72, 20, 44, 62, 6, 112, 107, 49, 86, 22, 68, 37, 97, 49, 68, 64, 14, 62, 28, 38, 87, 54, 60, 62, 60, 41, 65, 99, 78, 52, 27, 55, 25, 60, 79, 38, 89, 36, 59, 83, 75, 45], [9, 31, 53, 47, 33, 61, 65, 62, 63, 37, 67, 62, 59, 21, 29, 29, 48, 28, 44, 68, 48, 19, 61, 8, 54, 41, 39, 0, 69, 35, 44, 24, 44, 76, 71, 49, 48, 55, 53, 1, 61, 19, 69, 36, 29, 24, 56, 22, 52, 32, 39, 34, 24, 49, 62, 68, 72, 34, 18, 33, 27, 28, 54, 59, 71, 10, 28, 68, 37, 30], [76, 100, 84, 62, 102, 66, 13, 37, 41, 88, 13, 43, 43, 71, 51, 45, 117, 73, 48, 66, 50, 64, 63, 76, 38, 52, 72, 69, 0, 52, 29, 83, 75, 90, 82, 23, 82, 64, 22, 69, 78, 87, 8, 46, 61, 85, 55, 47, 67, 41, 36, 102, 64, 31, 8, 64, 6, 36, 78, 40, 85, 54, 41, 44, 31, 77, 95, 24, 76, 97], [44, 62, 82, 16, 64, 28, 55, 65, 69, 70, 44, 69, 25, 52, 7, 40, 78, 22, 9, 85, 62, 47, 27, 42, 60, 6, 20, 35, 52, 0, 23, 59, 24, 100, 93, 29, 77, 23, 49, 34, 85, 52, 48, 48, 10, 59, 22, 23, 74, 38, 43, 66, 50, 22, 44, 83, 57, 34, 34, 39, 37, 47, 61, 25, 70, 38, 62, 63, 66, 54], [53, 75, 76, 36, 77, 43, 32, 46, 50, 72, 23, 51, 25, 53, 22, 31, 92, 44, 22, 70, 48, 46, 40, 52, 43, 24, 44, 44, 29, 23, 0, 64, 47, 90, 82, 5, 73, 40, 28, 44, 76, 63, 26, 37, 32, 65, 33, 22, 64, 27, 28, 78, 48, 8, 21, 69, 34, 21, 51, 28, 57, 41, 45, 26, 48, 51, 72, 41, 63, 71], [16, 26, 35, 71, 28, 85, 76, 65, 64, 13, 85, 62, 82, 12, 52, 38, 40, 51, 67, 61, 47, 19, 85, 19, 57, 65, 62, 24, 83, 59, 64, 0, 68, 60, 58, 67, 30, 79, 63, 25, 47, 18, 85, 40, 53, 3, 80, 41, 42, 42, 48, 24, 21, 70, 77, 61, 85, 47, 37, 43, 45, 30, 55, 82, 76, 27, 18, 75, 21, 35], [51, 61, 97, 15, 62, 25, 79, 89, 92, 81, 66, 91, 39, 65, 28, 60, 74, 17, 27, 106, 83, 62, 26, 49, 83, 24, 6, 44, 75, 24, 47, 68, 0, 118, 112, 52, 92, 20, 73, 43, 103, 54, 71, 69, 19, 67, 28, 43, 92, 60, 65, 67, 66, 44, 68, 105, 81, 57, 32, 61, 29, 65, 84, 39, 94, 41, 64, 87, 81, 49], [72, 85, 25, 115, 87, 128, 77, 53, 49, 49, 99, 47, 114, 56, 93, 61, 95, 103, 105, 25, 42, 57, 126, 75, 51, 105, 112, 76, 90, 100, 90, 60, 118, 0, 8, 89, 30, 123, 69, 77, 15, 78, 97, 53, 100, 63, 119, 77, 26, 63, 61, 81, 52, 98, 88, 27, 88, 69, 93, 63, 102, 53, 49, 115, 63, 84, 77, 68, 40, 96], [69, 83, 24, 109, 85, 121, 69, 45, 41, 48, 91, 39, 107, 52, 87, 54, 94, 98, 99, 17, 34, 52, 119, 71, 43, 98, 107, 71, 82, 93, 82, 58, 112, 8, 0, 81, 28, 116, 61, 72, 10, 76, 89, 46, 94, 60, 112, 71, 20, 56, 54, 80, 47, 90, 80, 19, 80, 62, 89, 56, 98, 47, 41, 108, 55, 79, 75, 60, 37, 93], [57, 80, 77, 40, 82, 47, 27, 43, 48, 75, 19, 48, 27, 56, 28, 32, 97, 49, 26, 69, 47, 49, 44, 56, 40, 29, 49, 49, 23, 29, 5, 67, 52, 89, 81, 0, 74, 44, 24, 48, 75, 67, 21, 37, 37, 69, 36, 26, 63, 28, 28, 82, 50, 10, 16, 67, 29, 22, 56, 28, 62, 42, 43, 28, 44, 56, 77, 37, 65, 76], [44, 55, 5, 92, 57, 105, 71, 52, 49, 20, 88, 47, 96, 28, 70, 42, 66, 76, 84, 36, 33, 31, 104, 46, 46, 83, 86, 48, 82, 77, 73, 30, 92, 30, 28, 74, 0, 100, 60, 50, 18, 49, 87, 37, 75, 33, 98, 55, 19, 46, 47, 52, 27, 80, 78, 37, 82, 52, 65, 45, 73, 32, 43, 96, 64, 55, 47, 66, 11, 66], [64, 78, 104, 8, 79, 6, 71, 85, 89, 92, 53, 89, 23, 74, 29, 62, 92, 32, 18, 107, 84, 69, 6, 61, 81, 18, 22, 55, 64, 23, 40, 79, 20, 123, 116, 44, 100, 0, 67, 54, 108, 69, 58, 71, 26, 80, 9, 45, 96, 60, 64, 83, 73, 34, 57, 105, 70, 56, 48, 61, 47, 70, 82, 22, 88, 55, 79, 81, 89, 67], [59, 83, 62, 63, 85, 71, 12, 19, 23, 67, 30, 24, 51, 51, 45, 25, 100, 65, 49, 46, 28, 44, 68, 60, 17, 51, 68, 53, 22, 49, 28, 63, 73, 69, 61, 24, 60, 67, 0, 54, 57, 71, 28, 24, 55, 66, 60, 34, 45, 22, 16, 84, 43, 35, 20, 44, 22, 20, 67, 21, 75, 33, 20, 52, 21, 63, 78, 15, 54, 83], [10, 32, 55, 46, 34, 60, 65, 62, 64, 38, 67, 62, 58, 22, 28, 30, 49, 27, 43, 70, 49, 21, 59, 8, 55, 40, 37, 1, 69, 34, 44, 25, 43, 77, 72, 48, 50, 54, 54, 0, 63, 19, 69, 37, 28, 25, 55, 22, 53, 32, 40, 34, 25, 48, 62, 69, 72, 34, 16, 33, 26, 29, 54, 58, 72, 9, 29, 68, 38, 30], [59, 73, 15, 100, 75, 113, 66, 43, 40, 38, 87, 38, 100, 42, 79, 46, 84, 88, 91, 20, 29, 42, 111, 61, 40, 90, 97, 61, 78, 85, 76, 47, 103, 15, 10, 75, 18, 108, 57, 63, 0, 65, 85, 38, 85, 50, 105, 62, 12, 49, 48, 70, 38, 84, 76, 21, 77, 55, 79, 48, 88, 38, 37, 101, 55, 69, 65, 58, 26, 83], [11, 13, 53, 61, 15, 75, 82, 76, 77, 31, 86, 75, 77, 25, 46, 45, 30, 38, 61, 77, 60, 29, 75, 11, 69, 57, 49, 19, 87, 52, 63, 18, 54, 78, 76, 67, 49, 69, 71, 19, 65, 0, 88, 51, 44, 16, 72, 41, 59, 49, 55, 15, 33, 68, 80, 77, 91, 52, 22, 49, 28, 41, 67, 76, 87, 14, 10, 84, 39, 17], [77, 101, 90, 57, 103, 59, 21, 45, 49, 92, 5, 51, 36, 74, 49, 48, 118, 70, 43, 73, 56, 66, 56, 77, 45, 47, 68, 69, 8, 48, 26, 85, 71, 97, 89, 21, 87, 58, 28, 69, 85, 88, 0, 50, 58, 88, 49, 47, 73, 44, 40, 103, 67, 27, 9, 72, 14, 39, 77, 44, 83, 58, 48, 37, 40, 77, 97, 32, 80, 97], [40, 63, 40, 64, 65, 76, 36, 26, 26, 43, 51, 25, 62, 28, 42, 9, 79, 57, 53, 36, 13, 22, 74, 41, 18, 53, 64, 36, 46, 48, 37, 40, 69, 53, 46, 37, 37, 71, 24, 37, 38, 51, 50, 0, 51, 43, 67, 26, 26, 11, 10, 63, 20, 45, 41, 35, 47, 16, 53, 10, 62, 10, 17, 62, 36, 47, 56, 35, 30, 66], [38, 54, 80, 18, 55, 32, 63, 70, 73, 66, 54, 73, 34, 48, 10, 42, 69, 12, 18, 87, 64, 44, 31, 36, 64, 14, 14, 29, 61, 10, 32, 53, 19, 100, 94, 37, 75, 26, 55, 28, 85, 44, 58, 51, 0, 54, 28, 24, 74, 41, 47, 58, 48, 32, 53, 86, 66, 38, 24, 42, 27, 47, 65, 34, 76, 30, 54, 70, 64, 45], [16, 23, 38, 71, 25, 86, 78, 68, 67, 15, 87, 65, 83, 15, 53, 41, 37, 51, 68, 64, 50, 22, 85, 18, 60, 65, 62, 24, 85, 59, 65, 3, 67, 63, 60, 69, 33, 80, 66, 25, 50, 16, 88, 43, 54, 0, 81, 43, 45, 45, 50, 21, 23, 71, 79, 64, 88, 49, 36, 45, 43, 33, 59, 83, 79, 26, 15, 78, 24, 33], [65, 82, 102, 13, 83, 10, 63, 79, 83, 92, 44, 83, 13, 73, 28, 59, 97, 37, 14, 102, 79, 68, 8, 63, 75, 16, 28, 56, 55, 22, 33, 80, 28, 119, 112, 36, 98, 9, 60, 55, 105, 72, 49, 67, 28, 81, 0, 43, 93, 56, 59, 86, 71, 26, 49, 100, 62, 51, 52, 57, 53, 67, 77, 12, 81, 58, 82, 73, 87, 72], [30, 54, 59, 38, 56, 51, 44, 47, 50, 51, 45, 49, 42, 32, 16, 17, 71, 32, 29, 63, 40, 25, 49, 30, 41, 28, 38, 22, 47, 23, 22, 41, 43, 77, 71, 26, 55, 45, 34, 22, 62, 41, 47, 26, 24, 43, 43, 0, 51, 17, 23, 56, 28, 28, 40, 62, 51, 15, 33, 18, 41, 24, 41, 42, 54, 30, 50, 49, 45, 51], [51, 68, 19, 89, 70, 101, 55, 34, 31, 36, 75, 29, 88, 34, 67, 34, 81, 78, 79, 18, 17, 33, 99, 53, 29, 79, 87, 52, 67, 74, 64, 42, 92, 26, 20, 63, 19, 96, 45, 53, 12, 59, 73, 26, 74, 45, 93, 51, 0, 37, 35, 66, 28, 72, 64, 19, 66, 43, 70, 36, 79, 27, 26, 89, 46, 61, 61, 49, 22, 76], [37, 61, 49, 54, 63, 65, 34, 31, 33, 48, 44, 32, 51, 30, 32, 4, 78, 49, 42, 47, 24, 23, 63, 38, 24, 43, 54, 32, 41, 38, 27, 42, 60, 63, 56, 28, 46, 60, 22, 32, 49, 49, 44, 11, 41, 45, 56, 17, 37, 0, 7, 62, 23, 35, 35, 45, 43, 6, 47, 1, 55, 14, 25, 52, 40, 42, 56, 36, 37, 62], [44, 68, 50, 58, 70, 69, 28, 24, 26, 52, 41, 26, 53, 36, 38, 10, 85, 55, 46, 42, 20, 28, 67, 45, 17, 47, 60, 39, 36, 43, 28, 48, 65, 61, 54, 28, 47, 64, 16, 40, 48, 55, 40, 10, 47, 50, 59, 23, 35, 7, 0, 69, 28, 36, 31, 41, 38, 9, 54, 6, 63, 18, 18, 54, 32, 49, 62, 29, 40, 69], [26, 6, 56, 75, 6, 89, 96, 88, 88, 32, 101, 86, 92, 35, 61, 59, 16, 51, 76, 85, 70, 41, 89, 26, 80, 72, 62, 34, 102, 66, 78, 24, 67, 81, 80, 82, 52, 83, 84, 34, 70, 15, 103, 63, 58, 21, 86, 56, 66, 62, 69, 0, 43, 83, 95, 85, 105, 66, 35, 63, 38, 53, 79, 91, 99, 29, 6, 97, 44, 20], [23, 44, 32, 65, 46, 78, 55, 44, 44, 25, 67, 43, 70, 9, 43, 19, 60, 51, 57, 45, 27, 4, 77, 25, 37, 56, 60, 24, 64, 50, 48, 21, 66, 52, 47, 50, 27, 73, 43, 25, 38, 33, 67, 20, 48, 23, 71, 28, 28, 23, 28, 43, 0, 55, 58, 45, 65, 29, 41, 23, 51, 10, 35, 70, 56, 33, 37, 54, 16, 49], [58, 80, 84, 31, 81, 36, 37, 54, 58, 79, 22, 58, 17, 60, 23, 39, 96, 44, 17, 78, 56, 53, 34, 57, 50, 21, 41, 49, 31, 22, 8, 70, 44, 98, 90, 10, 80, 34, 35, 48, 84, 68, 27, 45, 32, 71, 26, 28, 72, 35, 36, 83, 55, 0, 24, 77, 37, 29, 53, 35, 58, 48, 52, 18, 55, 55, 77, 47, 71, 74], [69, 93, 81, 55, 95, 59, 15, 37, 42, 83, 11, 43, 37, 65, 43, 39, 110, 65, 41, 65, 48, 58, 57, 69, 37, 44, 65, 62, 8, 44, 21, 77, 68, 88, 80, 16, 78, 57, 20, 62, 76, 80, 9, 41, 53, 79, 49, 40, 64, 35, 31, 95, 58, 24, 0, 64, 13, 30, 71, 35, 78, 49, 40, 38, 34, 70, 89, 26, 71, 90], [68, 87, 35, 99, 89, 110, 51, 27, 23, 55, 74, 21, 94, 52, 78, 44, 100, 92, 87, 2, 22, 49, 108, 70, 27, 88, 99, 68, 64, 83, 69, 61, 105, 27, 19, 67, 37, 105, 44, 69, 21, 77, 72, 35, 86, 64, 100, 62, 19, 45, 41, 85, 45, 77, 64, 0, 61, 50, 86, 45, 95, 41, 24, 94, 36, 78, 79, 41, 41, 94], [79, 103, 84, 68, 105, 72, 11, 35, 39, 89, 19, 41, 49, 73, 56, 47, 120, 78, 54, 63, 49, 66, 69, 79, 37, 57, 78, 72, 6, 57, 34, 85, 81, 88, 80, 29, 82, 70, 22, 72, 77, 91, 14, 47, 66, 88, 62, 51, 66, 43, 38, 105, 65, 37, 13, 61, 0, 39, 83, 42, 90, 55, 40, 50, 27, 81, 98, 20, 77, 101], [40, 64, 55, 49, 67, 60, 31, 32, 35, 53, 38, 35, 46, 35, 29, 10, 81, 47, 38, 51, 28, 28, 58, 40, 26, 38, 52, 34, 36, 34, 21, 47, 57, 69, 62, 22, 52, 56, 20, 34, 55, 52, 39, 16, 38, 49, 51, 15, 43, 6, 9, 66, 29, 29, 30, 50, 39, 0, 47, 6, 55, 20, 27, 46, 39, 43, 60, 34, 43, 64], [21, 30, 70, 40, 31, 54, 77, 78, 79, 50, 74, 78, 59, 37, 30, 45, 45, 16, 43, 86, 65, 37, 54, 18, 70, 39, 27, 18, 78, 34, 51, 37, 32, 93, 89, 56, 65, 48, 67, 16, 79, 22, 77, 53, 24, 36, 52, 33, 70, 47, 54, 35, 41, 53, 71, 86, 83, 47, 0, 48, 9, 45, 70, 58, 86, 10, 32, 82, 54, 21], [38, 62, 49, 54, 64, 66, 33, 30, 32, 48, 44, 31, 52, 31, 33, 4, 79, 50, 43, 46, 23, 23, 64, 39, 23, 43, 55, 33, 40, 39, 28, 43, 61, 63, 56, 28, 45, 61, 21, 33, 48, 49, 44, 10, 42, 45, 57, 18, 36, 1, 6, 63, 23, 35, 35, 45, 42, 6, 48, 0, 56, 14, 24, 52, 39, 43, 57, 35, 37, 63], [30, 33, 78, 40, 33, 53, 85, 86, 88, 58, 80, 87, 61, 46, 35, 54, 45, 16, 45, 95, 74, 46, 53, 27, 79, 41, 25, 27, 85, 37, 57, 45, 29, 102, 98, 62, 73, 47, 75, 26, 88, 28, 83, 62, 27, 43, 53, 41, 79, 55, 63, 38, 51, 58, 78, 95, 90, 55, 9, 56, 0, 55, 79, 61, 95, 18, 36, 90, 62, 20], [30, 53, 36, 62, 55, 75, 45, 35, 36, 34, 58, 34, 64, 18, 40, 10, 69, 52, 53, 41, 20, 12, 73, 32, 28, 52, 60, 28, 54, 47, 41, 30, 65, 53, 47, 42, 32, 70, 33, 29, 38, 41, 58, 10, 47, 33, 67, 24, 27, 14, 18, 53, 10, 48, 49, 41, 55, 20, 45, 14, 55, 0, 27, 64, 46, 38, 46, 45, 23, 56], [57, 79, 45, 77, 81, 87, 29, 9, 9, 55, 51, 8, 69, 44, 56, 25, 95, 73, 64, 26, 10, 38, 84, 58, 3, 65, 79, 54, 41, 61, 45, 55, 84, 49, 41, 43, 43, 82, 20, 54, 37, 67, 48, 17, 65, 59, 77, 41, 26, 25, 18, 79, 35, 52, 40, 24, 40, 27, 70, 24, 79, 27, 0, 70, 21, 64, 72, 22, 41, 83], [68, 87, 100, 24, 89, 22, 53, 71, 75, 93, 32, 76, 1, 74, 30, 55, 103, 45, 16, 96, 74, 67, 19, 66, 68, 20, 38, 59, 44, 25, 26, 82, 39, 115, 108, 28, 96, 22, 52, 58, 101, 76, 37, 62, 34, 83, 12, 42, 89, 52, 54, 91, 70, 18, 38, 94, 50, 46, 58, 52, 61, 64, 70, 0, 71, 63, 86, 64, 86, 79], [76, 99, 65, 84, 101, 91, 19, 12, 15, 76, 44, 17, 70, 64, 66, 42, 115, 86, 70, 38, 31, 58, 88, 77, 19, 72, 89, 71, 31, 70, 48, 76, 94, 63, 55, 44, 64, 88, 21, 72, 55, 87, 40, 36, 76, 79, 81, 54, 46, 40, 32, 99, 56, 55, 34, 36, 27, 39, 86, 39, 95, 46, 21, 71, 0, 81, 93, 8, 62, 101], [11, 25, 60, 47, 26, 61, 74, 72, 73, 40, 75, 72, 63, 28, 33, 40, 41, 25, 47, 78, 58, 28, 61, 9, 64, 44, 36, 10, 77, 38, 51, 27, 41, 84, 79, 56, 55, 55, 63, 9, 69, 14, 77, 47, 30, 26, 58, 30, 61, 42, 49, 29, 33, 55, 70, 78, 81, 43, 10, 43, 18, 38, 64, 63, 81, 0, 24, 77, 44, 20], [20, 8, 52, 71, 10, 85, 90, 81, 81, 28, 95, 80, 87, 29, 56, 52, 22, 48, 71, 79, 64, 35, 85, 21, 74, 67, 59, 28, 95, 62, 72, 18, 64, 77, 75, 77, 47, 79, 78, 29, 65, 10, 97, 56, 54, 15, 82, 50, 61, 56, 62, 6, 37, 77, 89, 79, 98, 60, 32, 57, 36, 46, 72, 86, 93, 24, 0, 91, 39, 21], [73, 97, 67, 77, 99, 84, 11, 15, 19, 77, 36, 21, 63, 63, 60, 39, 113, 80, 63, 43, 33, 56, 81, 73, 20, 65, 83, 68, 24, 63, 41, 75, 87, 68, 60, 37, 66, 81, 15, 68, 58, 84, 32, 35, 70, 78, 73, 49, 49, 36, 29, 97, 54, 47, 26, 41, 20, 34, 82, 35, 90, 45, 22, 64, 8, 77, 91, 0, 62, 98], [33, 47, 16, 81, 49, 94, 66, 50, 48, 15, 81, 46, 86, 16, 59, 33, 60, 65, 74, 40, 30, 20, 93, 35, 43, 72, 75, 37, 76, 66, 63, 21, 81, 40, 37, 65, 11, 89, 54, 38, 26, 39, 80, 30, 64, 24, 87, 45, 22, 37, 40, 44, 16, 71, 71, 41, 77, 43, 54, 37, 62, 23, 41, 86, 62, 44, 39, 62, 0, 56], [26, 14, 71, 59, 14, 73, 94, 91, 92, 47, 94, 90, 79, 42, 50, 59, 25, 35, 63, 94, 76, 45, 73, 25, 84, 59, 45, 30, 97, 54, 71, 35, 49, 96, 93, 76, 66, 67, 83, 30, 83, 17, 97, 66, 45, 33, 72, 51, 76, 62, 69, 20, 49, 74, 90, 94, 101, 64, 21, 63, 20, 56, 83, 79, 101, 20, 21, 98, 56, 0]]
```

The solution that is found looks like this:

```
Objective: 70195
Route for vehicle 0:
 1 ->  4 ->  16 ->  51 ->  66 ->  45 ->  31 ->  9 ->  2 ->  36 ->  68 ->  13 ->  21 ->  52 ->  61 ->  43 ->  20 ->  48 ->  40 ->  33 ->  34 ->  19 ->  55 ->  62 ->  24 ->  11 ->  8 ->  7 ->  64 ->  67 ->  6 ->  56 ->  28 ->  42 ->  10 ->  54 ->  38 ->  50 ->  59 ->  15 ->  49 ->  57 ->  47 ->  14 ->  44 ->  29 ->  25 ->  18 ->  30 ->  35 ->  53 ->  12 ->  63 ->  46 ->  22 ->  5 ->  37 ->  3 ->  32 ->  26 ->  17 ->  60 ->  58 ->  65 ->  39 ->  27 ->  23 ->  0 ->  41 ->  69 -> 1
Distance of the route: 695m

Total Distance of all routes: 695m
```

But as far as I'm concerned this is no plausible problem since there is just one pickup delivery pair so shouldn't the best solution just be: depot -> pickup -> delivery -> depot. Another thing to add is that the distance matrix resembles random positioned points where the distance between each pair is the euclidian distance. I think this enforces my argument even more since depot -> pickup -> delivery -> depot is always a 'direct' way and thus must be the shortest path.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

By default, all nodes must be visited. If you do not want that, just do not create the node.

Alternatively, you can make them optional with the AddDisjunction() method.

See https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/penalties

Comment: Is there a way of not needing to visit all nodes besides not creating them? Some configuration parameter?

Comment: Can you show how to use the AddDisjunction() method in my code above to exclude the nodes that are not involved in the transport requests. I can't seem to find a way. When I try I get an error: ```F0000 00:00:1687428664.255643     220 routing.cc:2328] Check failed: delivery < size (37 vs. 3)```